# Loops in Python terminating Programm

Tags: python, loops, whitespace

I am new to coding and Python in general, and I can't figure this out. 
I added loops so that the program does not terminate every time there is a typo, however I messed up something with the second loop presumably.
I think it might be connected to the whitespace, but I can't figure it out.
The Programm terminates after taking in the "calories_burned" variable.

```
def start():

print("""This is a Weight Calculator, please follow the instructions.""")
name = input("What is your name? ")
age = int(input("How old are you? "))

if 19 <= age <= 78:

    height = float(input("How tall are you in cm? "))
    current_weight = float(input("How much do you currently weigh? "))
    goal_weight = float(input("How much do you want to weigh? "))
    calories_consumed = int(input("How many calories did you consume today? "))
    calories_burned = int(input("How many calories did you burn today? "))

    def activity():

        global rmr
        activity_factor = input("Choose an activity factor: Sedentary, Lightly active, Moderately Active, Very Active ")

        zif activity_factor == "sedentary":
            rmr = int(round(((10 * current_weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5) * 1.2))

        if activity_factor == "lightly active":
            rmr = int(round((10 * current_weight + 6.25 * height - 5 * age + 5) * 1.375))

        if activity_factor == "moderately active":
            rmr = int(round(((10 * current_weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5) * 1.550))

        if activity_factor == "very active":
            rmr = int(round(((10 * current_weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5) * 1.725))

        else:
            activity()

        daily_deficit = int((rmr + calories_burned - calories_consumed))
        print("Your daily deficit is: " + str(daily_deficit))

        import numpy
        mean_deficit = [daily_deficit]
        calculation_mean_deficit = int(round(7500 / numpy.mean(mean_deficit)))
        reach_goal = int(round((current_weight - goal_weight) * calculation_mean_deficit))

        print(mean_deficit)
        print(name + " it will take you " + str(calculation_mean_deficit) + " days to loose 1 kg.")
        print(name + " it will take you " + str(reach_goal) + " days to reach your goal.")

        choice = input("do you wish to continue Y/N?")

        if choice == "n":
            return
        else:
            start()
else:
    print("Invalid age")
    start()


start()
```

Comment: You are not _calling_ `activity`. You are just defining it.

Comment: You don't have any loops in your program at all. You are simulating loops with recursive calls, which is a reasonable thing to do in some languages, but not in Python. And I think that's related to your problem—you want to break out of the whole thing if `choice == "n"`, but you're actually just returning from `activity` and falling back into the outer `start` function that calls itself again. (I think—it's hard to tell with the indentation broken as posted here.) If you used `while` loops, then `return` would exit the whole function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the activity() function anywhere in your code, so once the program collects the inputs it doesn't do anything else and exits.

Also it's "lose" not "loose"